# How do I make a NSString function from a class then call it?

Tags: objective-c, database, class

I created an subclass NSObject "Database" which creates both Database.h and Database.m, what I want to do is, to make a class that calls the database.

I created a code like this

```
#import "Database.h"

@implementation Database
NSString* docsDir;
NSArray* dirPaths;
NSString* dbsePath;

NSString *getDB()
{
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    dbsePath = [[NSString alloc]
                initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 @"DBUntilAgo.sqlite"]];
    NSLog(@"1!%@",dbsePath);
    return dbsePath;
}


@end
```

Is it correct? and how do I make a call from it to another views? pls help. Im new to Xcode.

Comment: First of all this is not Objective C syntax. You then need to declare your getDB method in the .h file and the define is in .m file. Then you can Instantiate your DataBase object from anywhere and call getDB method on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should be your Database.h file**

```
@interface Database: NSObject
{

}

-(NSString *)getDB;
@end
```

**This should be your Database.m file**

```
#import "Database.h"

@implementation Database

-(NSString *)getDB {
    NSString* docsDir;
    NSArray* dirPaths;
    NSString* dbsePath;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    dbsePath = [[NSString alloc]
                initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 @"DBUntilAgo.sqlite"]];
    NSLog(@"1!%@",dbsePath);
    return dbsePath; } 
@end
```

**Then lets say from AppDelegate.m you can create something like this**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Database.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Database *db=[[Database alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@",[db getDB]);




    //    RootNavigationController *root=[[RootNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[RootNavigationController RootViewControllerCandidate]];
    //    [root setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    //    [self.window setRootViewController:root];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: You're welcome dude. Yea if you are using latest Xcode ARC should be in effect by default.